# Size of image depending of size of text in HTML

Tags: html, css, image

Is it possible to have a div which contains:

- On the left part a block of text
- On the right part on image

So that I don't have to specify any absolute size: I want the image to scale automatically to match the size of the block of text.

I already tried a lot of things, nothing worked, here is my current code:

```
<div id="home" class="cadre">   
    <div id="pic" style="float:right;height:180px;max-height:100%;">
        <img src="images/photo.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div style="width:70%;" id="texte">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried `height:100%` and a lot of variants, never worked :(

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8fqdt0s/2/

Comment: Any code, trying anything or at least any example ?

Comment: does this need to be repsonsive? What code do you have at this point? is the text dynamic?

Comment: I detailed my current code and attempts

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in your html :

```
<div>Bla bla bla
  <img class'myImg' ..../>
</div>
```

And in CSS :

```
.myImg
{
   float:right;
   width:25%; // of parent
   height:auto;
}
```

And the picture will autosized :)